# Need help to remove the icon on progress bar

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-progressbar

[image: Current Loading Screen]

I managed to run it perfectly on 4.1.1, but on 6.0, it shows that dropdown icon. How to remove the spinning icon?

EDITED: Here is the XML code for the progress bar on the current project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:fillViewport="false" />
        <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Paste your layout ...

Comment: post ur xml file..will solve it

Comment: i have added the code in the post

Comment: Don't put the spinner style

Comment: Thank you that did it for me

Comment: sorry turns out only works on emulator, on my own device didn't show any circular progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using a spinner style:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
```

You should use a ProgressBar style instead

Comment: thank you this fixed my other problem that i mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 0):

**This May help you**

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/your_progressbar_style" />
```